# Inverting holomorphisms: beyond a small neighbourhood?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Obviously, if $f(z)$ is holomorphic on an open connected set $D$ and $f'(z)$ never vanishes, then around each point in $D$, we can find a neighbourhood in which $f(z)$ is invertible.

But what general conditions ensure that $f(z)$ is invertible on the whole of $D$? If, for instance, on the disc of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ around $(1+0i)$, we cannot invert $f(z)=z^{100}$.

It will suffice, I suppose, if $\Re (f'(z))$ never attains $0$. But no stronger conditions come to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality $\operatorname{Re}f'>0$ is sufficient for global invertibility in a **convex** domain, where one can integrate it along line segments to obtain $\operatorname{Re} \frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}>0$ for all $a\ne b$. In general, it is not sufficient when the domain is not convex.

There are many sufficient *univalence criteria* (search for this term) for holomorphic functions on the unit disk. They often involve the [Schwarzian derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative) $Sf(z) = (f''/f')' -\frac12(f''/f')^2$.  The most notable is $|Sf(z)| \le 2/(1-|z|^2)^2$; Nehari's paper [Univalence criteria depending on the Schwarzian derivative](https://www.projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256048101) gives a few others.